# Remove a li from listview on splitbutton click with popup

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I know how to remove a list item from a listview on split-button click as you can see here:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VnUWA/1/)

code:

```
$('#produsele').children('li').on('click', function () {
    var selected_index = $(this).index();
    $(this).closest('li').remove()
    //alert('Selected Index = ' + selected_index);
});
```

But I want to be able to do it after a popup asks if you are sure you want to delete it, like in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urHP4/30/)

the

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="produsele">
    <ul id="listaprod" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="images/pic1.jpg" />
                        <h2>First product</h2>
                        <p>description</p></a>
    <a href="#sterge" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Delete</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">
                        <img src="images/pic2.jpg" />
                        <h2>Second product</h2>
                        <p>other description</p></a>
    <a href="#sterge" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Delete</a>

        </li>
    </ul>

    <div data-role="popup" id="sterge" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="b" class="ui-content" style="max-width:340px; padding-bottom:2em;">
            <h3>Delete product?</h3>
        <p>Do you want to remove this product from the list?</p>
        <input id="delButton" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-icon="check" type="button" value="Delete!" />
        <input id="giveupButton" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-icon="delete" type="button" value="No" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Can you help me? How do I reference the `<li>` from the main page, from inside the popup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
var li = '';
$(document.body).on('click', '.del' ,function(){
    li= $(this).parent();
    $('#sterge').popup("open");
});

$(document.body).on('click', '#delButton' ,function(){
    $('#sterge').popup("close");
    li.remove();
});

$(document.body).on('click', '#giveupButton' ,function(){
    $('#sterge').popup("close");
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vdq6a/)

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be is to add a click event to the `anchor` that shows the delete icon. And store the current li inside a variable.

The use the same variable to remove the li..

```
 var button = document.getElementById("delButton");
 button.onclick = deleItem;

 var $currli;

 $('a[data-rel=popup]').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    $currli = $(this).closest('li');
 });

 function deleItem() {
     console.log($currli)
     $currli.remove();
     $( "#sterge" ).popup( "close" );
 }
```

**Check Fiddle**

**Update**

Call `$( "#sterge" ).popup( "close" );` in the deleItem method

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urHP4/42/)**

Comment: Works great, but how do I get the popup to close after deleting the item?

Comment: Check updated code .. Also check the docs for more options.. http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/

Comment: Sorry... I was trying with $( "#popup" ).popup( "close" ); I do not know why. Must be the late hours (or early hours). **Thank you** you were of great help.

Comment: However there must be something wrong with my code. Where should I place the jscript in order to be fired? I placed it in the document.ready (all of it) and it does not work. Strangely it works in jsfiddle but it does not work in my page. What am I doing wrong? It looks like currli is not set somehow, because I also set the click event for the "No" button and the function only closes the popup. And this button works, But when I click the Delete button, the event fires (I placed an alert there to make sure) but the actual remove does not work

Comment: Check if jQuery is being included on the page.. Also check for any errors in the console of your developer tools

Comment: The jQuery is included in the page. However, strangely, the code proposed by @Susanth works perfectly, so now I do not know which answer to check since I am grateful to both of you for your fast and on-topic comments. I guess I will have to pick the one that worked out of the box (@Susanth) but **thank both of you**. Have a nice day